# Why does my request to the JIRA api to create an attachment return an empty array

Tags: node.js, jira-rest-api

I'm having trouble getting my request to jira cloud to add an attachment to an issue. It returns 200 but the response is an empty array.

```
const formData = new FormData();
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    let file = files[i];
    formData.append("file", file.content, file.name);
}

console.log(formData); // see below

let params = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://submissive.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/${createKey}/attachments`,
    data: formData.getBuffer(),
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
        'Authorization': getAuthHeader(user, apiToken),
        ... formData.getHeaders()
    }
};

console.log('params: ', params);

let response = await axios(params);
console.log(response);
console.log(response.data); // [] empty array

console.log('attachments added');
```

formdata:

```
FormData {
  _overheadLength: 143,
  _valueLength: 2946927,
  _valuesToMeasure: [],
  writable: false,
  readable: true,
  dataSize: 0,
  maxDataSize: 2097152,
  pauseStreams: true,
  _released: false,
  _streams: [
    '----------------------------470840621872458708605830\r\n' +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 01 2c 01 2c 00 00 ff e1 28 3a 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 06 01 06 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 02 ... 2946877 more bytes>,
    [Function: bound ]
  ],
  _currentStream: null,
  _insideLoop: false,
  _pendingNext: false,
  _boundary: '--------------------------470840621872458708605830'
}
```

Is it a problem the length is 0? I've tried adding the forma data with and without the extension method with the same results. I've confirmed I can add an attachment with the account I built my API credentials from. The file name is correct: 'file'. My only thought is maybe im ussing buffers incorrectly but the form log above makes it look correct.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone. I was having the same issue and the problem was with the call to `formData.append()`. The third argument needs to be an object.

```js
// get the attachment file

// what I originally had
formData.append("file", attachment.Body) // in my case the attachment.Body is the buffer

// what fixed the issue
const fileInfo = {
    filename: fileName, // e.g. MyDoc.pdf
    contentType: attachment.ContentType, // e.g. application/pdf
    knownLength: attachment.ContentLength, // e.g. 18059464
}

formData.append("file", attachment.Body, fileInfo)
```